# What kit enables iPhone or iPad use for wearable computing?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, hardware-recommendation

I am wondering if there are wearable computer kits for the iPhone or iPad, or are there resources on how to do it.

I would like to be able to, at a bare minimum, type text while walking, possibly do more like read text documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GoPad](http://www.gopad.ca/store/) should work with iPads 2 through 4.

[GoPad http://than.mn/pk](http://than.mn/pk)

Answer (score 1):

Wearable computing is an interesting problem. You can do some of it by getting something like the google glasses, which won't be released until next year at about $1500, or finding a vendor for the project. You would then have to get the adapter for your iDevice to output svga/dvi and interface that with the HUD (Heads up display)
Next, for input, you would likely have to get a bluetooth keyboard. There used to be a frogpad (not sure if they still make them) that supports bluetooth, but it is a chorded keyboard. Chorded keyboards take some getting used to, but can be very good and very fast once you do.

At the moment, I don't know of a kit you can buy to do this, it will likely take some work sourcing the parts like the glasses and keyboard.